# What does twisted.internet.error.ConnectError mean when I connect to a Landscape server?

Tags: landscape

I set up a handful of systems in landscape over the last week.

However, when I went to set up a handful more today, I recieved the following error message:

```
Request a new registration for this computer now? [Y/n]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectError: An error occurred while connecting: 2: No such file or directory.
```

What is going on?

Comment: That kind of error implies the broker could not start for some reason. Whatever the reason is likely a bug. Details about why can possibly be found in `/var/log/landscape/broker.log` .  I've heard of a few instances of this and have filed a bug. It would be great if you could comment with details (ubuntu release, landscape-client version, relevant log entries) to https://bugs.launchpad.net/landscape-client/+bug/1868730

Answer (score 0):

Please check or set the owner and filepermissions for client.conf:

```
chown landscape:root /etc/landscape/client.conf
chmod 600  /etc/landscape/client.conf
```